# How do I send a mouseDown event from a parent to a child component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, events

I am using React to create a Musical Synthesizer and I would like to trigger button events from keyboard events. How do I send events from a parent component to a child component?

I have tried attaching a listener to each child components button and dispatching button events from the parent, but this does not work.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

    handleKeyDown = event => {
        const key = event.key.toUpperCase();
        const evt = new MouseEvent("mousedown");
        document.getElementById(key).dispatchEvent(evt);
    }

    handleKeyUp = event => {
        const key = event.key.toUpperCase();
        const evt = new MouseEvent("mouseup");
        document.getElementById(key).dispatchEvent(evt);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div    id="main-content"
                    className="synthesizer-application"
                    onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
                    onKeyUp={this.handleKeyUp}
                    tabIndex="0">
                // Keyboard renders the keys
                <Keyboard />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default class Key extends React.Component {
    // Methods not shown
    render() {
        return (
            <button className="key"
                    id={this.props.letter}
                    onMouseDown={this.handleKeyPress}
                    onMouseUp={this.handleKeyRelease}>
                {this.props.letter}
            </button>
        );
    }
}
```

I expect the button to receive an event, but instead nothing happens.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you expect the `main-content` div to do? How does the Keyboard render the keys? The keyboard is the parent component that needs to pass the event handlers. [Take a look at this](https://www.javascriptstuff.com/how-to-pass-events-between-components/)

Comment: I am using the main-content div so the user only has to click on the web page to send keyboard events. I don't want the user to be forced to click on the keyboard div to play keys. Thank you I will check out the link.

Comment: So if I get you right you won't need listeners on your keys at all, you could just listen to everything in the parent component, manage the state there and pass down whatever you want to happen as props to the keys

Comment: That is what I ended up doing. It works right now, but the problem I see is that I have to reload every key when a single key is pressed. This might be a performance issue in the future :/

Comment: If it's ever gonna be that big, Redux or React's Context API might be your solution.

Comment: It will probably never become that big... there is just some part of me really wants to be as efficient as possible. Just looked up Reacts Context API, some good stuff there.